# Can't add an assets folder in Android Studio 3.6.3

Tags: android-studio

Windows 10
Android Studio 3.6.3

I was trying to add an assets folder to my Android Studio project, which as I understand, should be located under new->folder->Assets Folder in any context menu of the Project view.

Opening the context menu for the app/src/main folder in the Project view doesn't show the new->folder option. I've tried adding it through the File menu, alt+insert and context menus of different project directories. The folder option doesn't exist in any of those.

[contents of the context menu->new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HjhR.png)

Edit: I've also tried:

- Reinstalling Android Studio without importing user settings
- Restarting Android Studion with `Invalidate Cache & Restart`

Comment: Restart your IDE with `Invalidate Cache & Restart` Option. it will work for you.

Comment: I didn't work I'm afraid